# How to generate environment specific configuration using ng eject?

Tags: angular, webpack, angular-cli

`ng eject` generates `webpack.config.js` in the root folder of our project. How should I generate environment specific configuration? I'm using angular CLI and new to web pack.

```
weback.common.js
webpack.dev.js
webpack.prod.js
webpack.test.js
```

Answer (score 0):

By running `ng eject` you are getting webpack config based on `environment.ts`. Seams like you want to specify the other environment so you can do it like so:

`ng eject --environment=prod` doing so you are getting webpack config generated based on `environment.prod.ts`.

> If `ng eject` erroring like `Your package.json scripts must not contain a build script as it will be overwritten.`, use `--force` flag

To get more context on that check out this [comment](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/4907#issuecomment-286380049)